# file = open(ad, 'wb') TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
@bot.on_message(filters.command('song'))
def songs(_,message):
    msg = message.text.replace(message.text.split(' ')[0], '')
    videosSearch = VideosSearch(msg , limit = 1)
    f = videosSearch.result()
    nani = f['result']
    for link in nani:
        url = link['link']
        video = pafy.new(url)
        audiostreams = video.audiostreams
        best = video.getbestaudio()
        ad = best.download() 
        file = open(ad, 'wb')
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
        file.close()
```

i cant find the error please help

file = open(ad, 'wb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: Try replacing the `ad` with `"ad"`

Comment: its just creating  a new text file

Comment: The returned value from `best.download()` that you assigned to `ad` is a NoneType. Make sure something is downloaded and/or written to a file or said file is returned. In addition to this, you're trying to send `open`, which you can't do. You need to specify a path to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other two replies aren't really getting the issue at hand, I'm going to chip in here.

---

On these Lines:

```py
    ad = best.download() 
    file = open(ad, 'wb')
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
    file.close()
```

You assign the result of `best.download()` to `ad`, which you want to send with Pyrogram. Since you get a TypeError on `open()` it is clear that `open()` didn't get the type it expected, namely a `NoneType`. You have to make sure that something is downloaded, and that the method returns a value you can use.

Maybe try the caveman approach and use `print(ad)` before trying to `open()` it.

---

In addition to all that: Pyrogram does not support sending a file representation (`open()`). You can open a file in bytes mode, read the bytes and use that with BytesIO, but when you have an actual file on your system, you can just use the path to the file: `app.send_document(chat_id, "my_file.webm")`.

See the Documentation for [`app.send_document()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_document#pyrogram.Client.send_document).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
file = open(ad, 'wb')
```

With This:

```
file = open('ad', 'wb')
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\advanced\save_file.py", line 125, in save_file
    raise ValueError("File size equals to 0 B")
ValueError: File size equals to 0 B

Comment: @Yato Either Your File Is Corrupted Or, Your file has no data in it

Comment: @Yato Is your file only called `"ad"` or it has some extentions to it? like `"*.mkv"` for a WebM file